Continuing run even when sending WM_PAINT in Direct3D 11
I'm developing a game by Win32 and Direct3D 11, but when I move or resize the window (WM_PAINT event), the game pauses run:

So, how can I keep the game runs even when I move or resize the window?
This the code in game loop:
while (msg.message != WM_QUIT) {  
  if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    TranslateMessage(&msg), DispatchMessageW(&msg);
     
  // code of the game (renderering and mechanics)
}

And this the WndProc():
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  if (message == WM_CLOSE) {
    DestroyWindow(hwnd), PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
  }
  return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

I looked this question, but it talks about Direct2D (and I want Direct3D 11).

WM_PAINT is not sent when the window is being dragged. And regarding why your game is freezing while the window is being dragged that depends on how you wrote your code, you'll want to include at least how you currently handle windows events and where you draw in the question. Code please, not a description.

Dragging and resizing are modal events they are sent to the window, not to your application loop .... i'd recommend you use SDL3 with the new SDL_MAIN_USE_CALLBACKS so it will be handled for you, otherwise you will need to handle the event yourself from the window WNDPROC and call the redraw functions from within the event handler .... but not call it too frequently that your app is stuck .... just let sdl3 handle it for you and call it a day.

@Cubic Actually, I forgot to include the code . Thanks for reminding me! I've edited the question and added the code.

@Ahmed_AEK Thank you for the suggestion, but I prefer to write the codes myself (if possible).

It is like if (message == WM_MOVE && enough_time_passed()) { redraw_screen(); } in your WNDPROC

For example 'main loops' see GitHub.

Whether have you tried to call InvalidateRect inside WM_PAINT?

@Ahmed_AEK Idk what you're trying to say.

@Chuck_Walbourn So where's the problem?

@Jeaninez - MSFT I'm not using Direct2D and Win32 for rendering, I'm using Direct3D 11. And the Problem isn't only in rendering. The entire game code is affected. The game freezes when I move or resize the window, and it returns to normal when I stop move or resize the window. The GIF shows the player hasn't touched the ground yet when the window is moved (If the Problem isn't only in rendering, the player already touched the ground when resizing or moving the window).
